# Spring boot gateway error - Unable to find RoutePredicateFactory with name path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm using Spring boot cloud gateway.
Spring version is 2.3.4.RELEASE
My eureka server is working well and other configurations are working well.
But when I gonna run the cloud gateway the Spring gives an error like bellow.

```java
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find RoutePredicateFactory with name path
```

My cloud gateway configurations are like this.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: sripy-client
          uri: localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - path=/client/
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
server:
  port: 8989
```

and porm.xml  like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>example.gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>example.gateway</name>
    <description>example gateway</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

please help me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is your predicates > path in yml file. the first letter must be a capital letter, in your case p of the path must be capital  like this `- Path=/client/`

Entire yml file

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: sripy-client
          uri: localhost:8080
          predicates:
            - Path=/client/ #first letter must be a capital letter 
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
server:
  port: 8989
```